# Ubuntu 23.10 - Pressing ALT key closes window abruptly

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 23.10

When pressing ALT Key alone some windows close. First it shows the menu bar, like it should when ALT key is pressed, followed by window closing. This goes away if I reboot or even log out and log in. It is also random. Problem is not found on all window. Any suggestions as to what the problem could be? I check keyboard mapping for custom shortcuts, but none found.

Comment: "First it shows the menu bar, like it should when ALT key is pressed," That is not how it should. Alt by itself will not trigger the window menu. I suspect a keyboard problem: connect a different keyboard and see whether the issue reproduces.

Comment: I used another keyboard, the problem persists.

Comment: It will be good to add that information in your question. Also provide information ion your desktop environment, and perhaps even on your hardware - the issue still could be there. Use "edit" to update your question.